# How can i open a new window on click a button say submit button and apply a functionality present in another component to show some data?

Tags: angular

I m trying to displaying few graphs in angular using chartjs and it is rendered fine on clicking a submit button. But issue is i want to render charts on a new window on clicking submit button. i know we can provide window.open("",_blank) but how to get graph data attributes to new window in angular?

Comment: It would be easier to store the graph data in a service. You can then use it in as many components as you want to.

Comment: my doubt is not about component to component communication. How to feed graph data to a new window which will open on a button click.

Comment: You might also be able to solve your probling by using localStorage/sessionStorage?

Comment: yeah i use mongodb and fetch data from there, but got stuck on how to render it in new window on graph html variables. Below is a rough hard coded testing code shows what i am trying to do.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-krarjy?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

As you stated, you should use window.open() to open the new window. That window should initialize a component. In that component you should have the graph data attributes.

Comment: yeah thats what i am thinking of and created a graph-component and moved all html,ts,css code over there. How to initialise that component in new window. For me what is happening is parent page html data from where i am clicking submit button is showing in new window.

Comment: sure thanks for your help. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-krarjy?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts